# Regular Expression for img src using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want RE for this string pattern:

```
src="http://www.prphotos.com/f/1335/CSM-001335/Robert-Pattinson,-Reese-Witherspoon-Water-for-Elephants-New-York-City-Premiere---Arrivals.jpg"  border="0"
```

I am using:

```
<img.[\w+\s+\d+\W]*/>
```

Also do I have to write different RE for different languages like javascript,PHP etc?

Comment: I would use a real dom parser. But hey.

Comment: The usual approach for this is to use a HTML parser. What is your use case? What kind of data are you searching in?

Comment: The question is ambiguous: Are you trying to match any image tag, only image tags with src="..." and border="...", only image tags from prpphotos.com, only image tags of a certain type from this particular site, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img [^>]*src=".*?[^\]"[^>]*/>
```

You may need to write `\` as `\\`

Comment: Thanks alot it worked, now I just wanna extract src, or can it return in array so I can use src.

Comment: that modification will cause a parse fail if there is a url with "s inside